# Android GridView (Caldroid) scroll margin on the bottom

Tags: android, gridview, scrollview, caldroid

I have a Caldroid Fragment that generates a calendar based on a GridView. It takes the complete screen. Then I added an AdView on the bottom of this activity, the problem is that banner covers some cells of the grid so user can't click on them. Basically, I want to set a margin in the inner part of the GridView to allow the user to scroll down the calendar, and when the calendar reach at the end, it continues scrolling for some more margin. This margin will be set with the height of the banner.

I am up to modify the caldroid code if necessary but I can't find how to produce this effect with a GridView. Setting a bottom padding avoids overlapping the AdView but by discarding the whole width, I would like to see the calendar at right and left of the banner when it is not completely scrolled down.

POSSIBLE SOLUTIONS:

-Maybe by adding a margin to the cells produced by the adapter will do it, but I need to know if they are from the last row. using getItemId always returns 0, and the methods getClipBounds and getClipToOutline are limited to API 21.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **android:clipToPadding="false**" with  android:paddingBottom= in your GirdView

```
<GridView android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="16dip"
    android:clipToPadding="false" />
```

Comment: @XaviGG if this not working please specify in detail your problem

Comment: Yes, it is what I just found :) Great parameter! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get why you need **inner** margins. 
Can't you put your GridView and your AdView in the same RelativeLayout

On the GridView

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginBottom="x"
```

On the AdView

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

x being the height of your AdView

No overlapping, functional scroll.